# React 0.13.3 does not call ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I have an hard time trying to understand why `ComponentDidMount` is not called in the following code.

```
var React = require ('react');

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { indexes: [ ] };
      }

      ComponentDidMount () {
        console.log('mounted');
      }

      render () {
        return (
          <div className="sidebar">
            <nav className="nav">
              <ul>
                {this.state.indexes.map((itm) => (
                  <li key={itm.id}><a href="#">{itm.name}</a></li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        );
      }
    };

module.exports = Sidebar;
```

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

ComponentDidMount => componentDidMount ? case sensitive

Comment: I feel kind of silly right now. Spent a lot of time trying to figure out what was wrong without noticing the capital 'C'.

Comment: But it's kind of funny because for me it was "broken" due to a spelling mistake as well. This answer serves as a great reminder that, yes, the spelling mistake is the number one reason by far of this not working :)